# SwipeView is too slow when changing background for each fragment

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

First of all, sorry for my English.

I'm trying to add a Swipe View to a FragmentActivity. I've followed the android doc from http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html among other.

I've got the FragmentActivity, the FragmentPagerAdapter (I've tried also a FragmentStatePagerAdapter), the Fragment and the other elements required by the doc (xml and so on).

I'm just developing a simple base for an app that will be extended soon, but by the moment I just wanted to show the same layout with different background for each position of this Swipe View.

In the Fragment I have the following (The FragmentPagerAdapter shares the position using the Bundle):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_initial_promo_swipe1, container, false);

    int position = this.getArguments().getInt("position", 0);
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            rootView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.intro1_screen);
            break;
        case 1:
            rootView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.intro2_screen);;
            break;
        case 2:
            rootView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.intro3_screen);
            break;
        default:
            rootView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.intro1_screen);
    }

    return rootView;
```

The thing is that just changing the background of the view in the fragment is making the swipe extremly slow (in a real device). The log is displaying the message:

"Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

If I remove the code setting the background, the issue disappear (but obviusly all pages have the same background).

I've read that processing images could be the source of this issue, but I wonder what would be the way then to implement a simple funcionality like this (a swipe view showing in each page different layouts or at least the same layout but with different images).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are on right direction. This is because images are huge. You can use `TranslateDrawable` for smooth translation of backgrounds and resizing image resources as seen on android dev guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is facing the same issue:

The problem disappears when the size of the image to load is reduced. I was working with images with too much resolution. Once the images were smaller, the transition became smoother.